# Will a 12.28" x 4.2" x .68" PCIe card fit in a Dell R510?

Tags: dell-poweredge, asterisk, pci-express

I am planning for a phone server and plan to get a Dell R510 to house two Asterisk 2400 series PCIE cards. (model 1AEX2406EF to be exact). I know the card is 12.28" x 4.2" x .68" (31.19 x 10.67 x 1.72 cm) and it will work in PCIe slots with 4x 8x and 16x. When I look into the Dell manual, it looks like something would block the full length of the card, but I can't tell. I find varying pictures and videos of the insides that makes it even more confusing.

Anyone know for sure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is a reason Dell writes a comprehensive technical guide for these kind of systems: To answer that kind of question. See http://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/dell-poweredge-r510-technical-guide.pdf

Spoiler: It supports only one full length card.

Comment: I searched that thing high and low before. Thanks to you, I finally found where it tells, and will know in the future (For everyone else, it's in the section "10 I/O Slots, Riser 1 Detail"). Thank you.